# after injecting html how to bind scope of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I my controller I am adding a html by this code

```
 var promise=productService.getProduct(); 
var template = $http.get('resources/template/Product.html').then(function(html){



   promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.productOrProducts = $sce.trustAsHtml(html.data);
       $compile($scope.productOrProducts)($scope);

   })
});
```

in the html.data I have directive which uses the $scope variables.but Its not able to bind all variable with those directive 
what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Product.html, you don't need to use things like `{{$scope.value}}`, just use `{{value}}` - you bound it to the scope already.

Comment: I am not doing that its just {{value}}